# How to show map with 3D buildings with google maps js api

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am building a web-page using Google maps js api. I need the map type which shows all 3D buildings view provided by Google earth, just like the Google's map application where you can see all 3D buildings in the earth view.
I don't want to use the Google earth API because it's deprecated.
Any way to achieve that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Google seems to be silent about 3D features in Javascript API. Closest I can get to this are Styled Maps but nowhere does it specifically indicate 3D. Only [Android](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/views#introduction) implementations are available as of now.

Answer (score 0):

At this moment, the javascript API generates 3d buildings in map-view, with no option to turn this off.
The google maps website shows 2d buildings, which includes housenumbers. This information seems more accurate than the 3d-buildings map-view. But the options to toggle between various map layers is a long standing omission in the javascript API.