# Adding 3D model KMZ with Google Maps API: is it possible?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kmz

I'm wondering if it's possible to add a 3D model made in Sketchup, exported o KMZ format, to a Google Map, with the Google Maps API. I was able to add KMZ layers that contained simple data as landmarks and such, but when I try to load the 3D model KMZ, the map just shows a default house file icon.

The test map can be accessed here: http://thebob.com.br/maptest/kmz_test.html

The KMZ file is hosted here: https://sites.google.com/site/dmgckmlfiles/kml-files/Bulk_carrier_1509.kmz

At this point I'm just guessing it's not possible to add 3D models like this into Google Maps (as the exact same thing happens if I import the file through My Maps), but I want to make sure of that before giving up.

Thanks in advance for any info!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well if you are pertaining in [Google JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial), Yes this API does support the KMZ as you can see in this [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kmllayer#supported-elements) about Supported KML elements. But the 3D object is not.

Also, according to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36379691/how-to-show-map-with-3d-buildings-with-google-maps-js-api/36446066#36446066), that 3D is not yet features in Javascript API. Closest things to this are Styled Maps. Only the [Android](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/views#introduction) implementations are available as of now.

But I found this [tutorial](https://github.com/OSMBuildings/OSMBuildings) that can help you if you still want 3D objects.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! That OSM Buildings project seems interesting, I'll check it out!